# How to bind multiple ports in OpenShift pod YAML config?

Tags: kubernetes, binding, openshift, port, kubernetes-pod

**How to bind multiple ports of a pod to make them visible on the pod IP?**

Something analogous to Docker's `docker run  -p 1234:5555  -p 6789:9999  my_image`

The only example of YAML definition I've found in documentation and tutorials uses single port without binding:

```
spec:
  containers:
    - name: my_container
      image: 'my_image'
      ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
```

Could you give a link to the documentation describing the case or a short example of binding multiple ports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`spec.containers.ports` is an array, which means you can specify multiple ports like so in your Pod definition:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: pod-multiple-ports
  labels:
    app: pod-multiple-ports
spec:
  containers:
  - name: my-container
    image: myexample:latest
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
    - containerPort: 443
```

Comment: Actually, I've found this experimentally. I agree it is obvious, but what stopped them from adding this into the docs? )))